# Why do VMs need to be "stack machines" or "register machines" etc.?

Tags: virtual-machine, bytecode

<sub>(This is an extremely newbie-ish question).</sub>

I've been studying a little about Virtual Machines.

Turns out a lot of them are designed very similarly to physical or theoretical computers.

I read that the JVM for example, is a 'stack machine'. What that means (and correct me if I'm wrong) is that it stores all of it's 'temporary memory' on a stack, and makes operations on this stack for all of it's opcodes.

For example, the source code `2 + 3` will be translated to bytecode similar to:

```
push 2
push 3
add
```

My question is this:

JVMs are probably written using C/C++ and such. If so, why doesn't the JVM execute the following C code: `2 + 3`..? I mean, why does it need a stack, or in other VMs 'registers' - like in a physical computer?

The underlying physical CPU takes care of all of this. Why don't VM writers simply execute the interpreted bytecode with 'usual' instructions in the language the VM is programmed with?

Why do VMs need to emulate hardware, when the actual hardware already does this for us?

Again, very newbie-ish questions. Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you considered what *non* virtual machines are based on?

Comment: @MichaelT You mean physical machines?

Comment: Of course, most Javascript VMs aren't stack machines or register machines -- V8 / IonMonkey / Chakra / etc. are VMs that implement Javascript. A "VM" is just an interpreter or JIT compiler which can implement any language the designer so desires.

Comment: @BillyONeal So for example if I'm writing a VM for some language and I'm writing it in C: the VM parses the bytcode line 'print "hi"', and executes `printf("hi");`: is this considered a VM? It has no 'stack' or 'registers' and or anything.

Comment: @Prog: Yep, that's correct.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

A machine, virtual or not, needs a *model of computation* which describes how computation is carried out on it. By definition, as soon as it computes, it implements some model of computation. The question then is: What model should we choose for our VM? Physical machines are constrained by what can be effectively and efficiently done in hardware. But, as you note, virtual machines have no such constraints, they are defined in software using arbitrarily high level languages.

There are, in fact, virtual machines that are high-level as you describe. **They are called programming languages**. The C standard for example dedicates the bulk of its pages to defining a model for the so-called "C abstract machine" which describes how C programs behave, and by extension (as-if rule) how a conforming C compiler (or interpreter) should behave.

Of course, we usually don't call that a virtual machine. A VM is usually takes to mean something lower-level, closer to hardware, not intended to be directly programmed, designed to be executed efficiently. This selection bias means that something that accepts high-level composable code (like what you describe) wouldn't be considered a VM *because* is executes high-level code.

But to get the to the point, here are some reasons to make a VM (as in, something targeted by a bytecode compiler) register-based or the like. Stack and register machines are extremely simple. There's a sequence of instructions, some state, and semantics for each instruction (a function State -> State). No complex tree reductions, no operator precedence. Parsing, analysing and executing it is very simple, because it's a minimal language (syntactic sugar is compiled away) and designed to be machine-read rather than human-read.

In contrast, parsing even the simplest C-like languages is quite hard, and executing it requires non-local analyses like checking and propagating types, resolving overloads, maintaining a symbol table, resolving *string* identifiers, turning linear text into a precedence-driven AST, and so on. It builds on concepts that come natural to humans but have to be painstakingly reverse engineered by machines.

JVM bytecode, for example, is emitted by `javac`. It virtually never needs to be read or written by humans, so it's natural to gear it towards consumption by machines. If you optimized it for humans, the JVM would just on every startup read the code, parse it, analyze is, and then convert it into an intermediate representation resembling such a simplified machine model *anyway*. Might as well cut out the middle man.

Comment: So what you're saying is that compiling everything to instructions on the stack (i.e. `System.out.println("hi");` is compiled to some instruction on a stack, `int a = 7` is compiled to an instruction on the stack, etc.) makes executing the program simple and more efficient?

Comment: @Prog Basically, yes. But not just execution, also analysis. *Everything* that is done programmatically.

Comment: Still, I don't understand why `2 + 3` is compiled to `push 2 push 3 add`. The `add` step at the end is executed by the JVM anyway by running the C code `2 + 3`. There's no other way for the programmers of the JVM to do this. Why not compile it to `2 + 3`, and have the JVM just execute the C code `2 + 3` (assuming it's written in C) right away?

Comment: @Prog The JVM author can't just write `2 + 3` in the JVM source code because the JVM has to work with any program doing any operations in any order. Building C source code and deferring to a C implementation just pushes the same problem into the C implementation (and can't be done easily, let alone efficiently). There has to be some data structure that describes the program, so that it can be interpreted and JIT compiled, and "human readable source code" is an awful choice of data structure for reasons outlined above.

Comment: @Prog The interpreter code inside a hypothetical JVM goes like this: `if i.is_int_push() { stack.push(i.argument) } else if i.is_add() { stack.push(stack.pop() + stack.pop()) }`.

Comment: Sorry but I really want to understand: if we're going to add 2 and 3 anyway, why not skip the `stack.push(i.argument) /*..*/ stack.push(i.argument)` phase, and jump right to the `stack.push(i.argument1 + i.argument2)`? Seems odd to do `push(num1) push(num2) add`.

Comment: @Prog `2 + 3` is language construct, there's no + operator in the vm. `2 + 3` is probably translated to `2 3 +`, which is then compiled to `push 2, push 3, add`.

Comment: @Prog You seem too focused on the specific case of 2 + 3. What about `a + b`? Then the values to add don't come from `i.argument{1,2}`, they are loaded from local variables. What about `frobnicate(x[i]) + (Foo.bar() * 2)`? Using this design, there is only one `add` operation (for `int`) and it works independently of how the addends were computed. Plus, an instruction that adds *only* integer literals would be pointless: Its result could just as well be pre-computed (i.e. instead of `add(2,3)` it should be `push(5)`).

Comment: In Java's case, the fundamental reason to create a virtual machine was to make Java write-once, run anywhere.  It separates the Java language from the runtime environment.  Java runs on a wide variety of hardware where the number of registers available differ, so stack based was more flexible.  In the .Net case, it was to separate the run time environment (CLR) from the several languages that compile to that byte code.  In retrospect, that decision enabled .Net Core to be feasible and now it can run in operating systems it wasn't originally written for.

Comment: The Virtual Machine approach provides the ability to compile one binary and deploy it to a wide range of hardware and operating systems.  In contrast to C, the library linking and type sizes will probably be different in Linux vs. Windows and Intel vs. ARM.  You can't take a binary compiled in one environment and expect it to work in one that it wasn't built for, even though the source code would still work if you recompile it in the new environment.  Virtual machines separate out those details so the same binary works without having to recompile it.

Answer (score 26):

This answer focuses on the JVM, but in fact it applies to any VM.

> Why do VMs need to emulate hardware, when the actual hardware already does this for us?

They don't, but it makes the VM much simpler and portable: A VM that emulates hardware can use the same computational model than any hardware CPU.

The JVM in particular was built with portability in mind, in fact it was built so it could even be implemented in hardware (it may be hard to believe today, but the [origin of Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28software_platform%29#History) was in the embedded world - specifically, controllers for interactive television).

If you have a goal like this, it is desirable that the VM operates as close to a physical machine as possible, because translating to actual machine code becomes easier and thus faster. Once you have the opcodes of the VM, in theory, all you have to do is translate to opcodes of the CPU the program actually runs on. In practice it is not exactly that simple.

> I mean, why does it need a stack, or in other VMs 'registers' - like in a physical computer?

Using a stack based virtual machine model has the advantage that it can be easily transferred to both register and stack machines, while the opposite is not necessarily true. A register-based VM would need to  make assumptions about the number of registers, the size of the registers etc. With a stack machine, no such assumptions are necessary.

> The underlying physical CPU takes care of all of this. Why don't VM writers simply execute the interpreted bytecode with 'usual' instructions in the language the VM is programmed with?

Well, that's what such VMs do, they interpret bytecode. Even the JVM actually does that, at least before JIT (just-in-time) kicks in: it interprets the byte codes and executes the statements in the language the JVM was written in (typically C or C++, but there is even one written in JavaScript, [Doppio](http://int3.github.io/doppio/about.html)). Note, however, that even such statements were translated to machine code by a compiler and actually look very similar to what the Java compiler produces - namely, they use registers and the stack to perform their work. Note the use of "interpreted" v.s. "compiled" languages becomes [somewhat blurry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21006440/890242) at this point.

Comment: Of course, anything that can be implemented in software can be implemented in hardware. Also, the JVM currently (hotspot) is a JIT compiler -- it does *not* execute the statements in the language the JVM was written in. If it did, Java would perform terribly and would be nowhere near as viable a platform as it is today. (Hell, most Javascript implementations would be faster)

Comment: @BillyONeal "Rather than compiling method by method, just in time, the Java HotSpot VM immediately runs the program using an interpreter, and analyzes the code as it runs to detect the critical hot spots in the program. Then it focuses the attention of a global native-code optimizer on the hot spots. " quoted from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/whitepaper-135217.html#2, section "Hot Spot Detection"

Comment: Yes. "Native code optimizer" == JIT compilation. There is an interpreter phase for code which doesn't appear to be "hot" to avoid JITing rarely used things. But that doesn't mean no JITing is done at all.

Comment: Thanks for answering. What I gathered from your answer is that the reasons to emulate hardware in the VM (aka with 'stacks' or 'registers' etc.) is because it makes it easy to later compile the bytecode or the source code to actual machine code of a physical CPU. However apart from that - is there anything to gain from emulating hardware in a VM? I still don't understand why somebody designing a VM would think in terms of a 'stack machine' or 'register machine' etc. when in fact we're talking about software. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Prog Ok, you have a programming language, say X. How will you run its programs? You can either interpret the source or compile it to machine code, or compile it into some intermediate code. Now you have another programming language, Y, and want to implement it using X. If both implementations are interpreter, you will have the interpreter of Y running on the interpreter of X, and this will be very slow.

Comment: @Prog, continued: The intermediate code of the Y VM ***generated*** by whatever implementation, even running on top of the X interpreter, will run much faster (and in the case of the X interpreter it is _the code generation_ that will be slow.). Note that the Y VM must be implemented in native code, otherwise it will be an intermediate code interpreter on top of another intermediate code interpreter.

Comment: @Prog Once your program in Y is translated (interpreted) to the language of the VM, say C, how do you want to run it? Well in fact, there are VMs that can translate new source code into byte code at run-time (e.g. Python), but that's just pushing the problem down one level. In the end, the VM needs to issue code that can be executed by the CPU -- the most efficient way is to use the same computational model, and as explained above, stack machines are the simplest. What else do you propose, if not stack or register machines?

Comment: "it interprets the byte codes and executes the statements in the language the JVM was written in". Are you saying that JVM compiles bytecode into C code?

Answer (score 15):

*Why do VMs need to be “stack machines” or “register machines” etc.?*

They do not. If you need a virtual machine, it may be anything.

The existing virtual machines have appeared as solutions to the situations like: *A really brilliant idea has come to my head, I have invented a new programming language! But I have to generate code. (What a boring task!) But I do not want to generate i8086 code because it's ugly, and I do not want to generate 68k code because everyone else is using Intel. There's also VAX, but I don't have any VAX, neither a computer nor a VAX book. Therefore I will generate code for some processor that does not physically exist and implement that processor in software. The spec of that VM will make a chapter in my thesis. In theory, it will be possible to compile it to native code of any processor, but that will not be me.*

On the other hand, the notation like "2+3" probably will not be used by VMs in foreseeable future because it implies doing a lot of transformation before something may be executed.

Comment: Thanks for answering. So what I gathered from your answer, is that the motivation to design a VM that emulates physical CPUs is because it makes it easy to later implement compilers that compile to actual machine code. But other than that - are there any advantages to designing a VM in terms of a 'stack machine' or a 'register machine' etc.?

Comment: Registers require register allocation algorithms, that need both theory and debugging. A stack machine (esp a zero-operand one) can just place the data on the stack. OTOH, hardware usually implements a limited amount of registers rather than a variable-sized stack. So stacks are easier for software, registers are easier for hardware and probably therefore a bit faster.

Answer (score -2):

To answer the actual question that was asked.  The term "virtual MACHINE" means that ALL software/hardware are simulated/emulated. If you use the underlying software/hardware to execute the instructions then you do not have a VM, you have a compiler/interpreter.

Comment: is this merely your opinion or you can back it up somehow?

Comment: @Kyrelel that's untrue. "ALL" hardware is emulated in "system" or "full" VM. Not all VMs are full. For example, BSD VM layer is named "virtual machine", despite hardware is not emulated there.

Comment: I don't think the question is necessarily about terminology, but rather why virtual machines implement functionality that is seemingly already handled by the actual hardware